# Bootstrap vue b-modal does not highlight the field on submission of the data

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-vue

I am using the `bootstrap vue` to design my application. Within the application, I am using the `b-modal`. Some of the fields in `b-modal` are required so I would like to highlight them if the user has not provided information to them. In normal bootstrap which I have used in other applications, it was highlighting the field and showing a default message `field is required` but in the `bootstrap-vue` I am not getting any such message by default. Can someone please tell me what needs to be done about it?

Following is the `bootstrap vue modal` code I have:

```
<template>
  <b-modal
    id="formSubmission"
    size="lg"
    title="Basic Details"
    :visible="visibility"
    style="width: 100%"
    @cancel="hideModal"
    @ok="submitModal($event)"
  >
    <b-form-select v-model="type" class="form-control" required>
      <b-form-select-option value="type1">
        Type1
      </b-form-select-option>
      <b-form-select-option value="type2">
        Type2
      </b-form-select-option>
    </b-form-select>

    <div v-if="type == 'type1'">
      <input
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        style="width:200px"
        autocomplete="off"
        placeholder="Enter Name"
        :required="type == 'type1'"
      >
    </div>
  </b-modal>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      visibility: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    hideModal () {
      this.visibility = false
    },

    submitModal (event) {
      event.preventDefault()
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

What I want to do is highlight the field which is required during the submission? I want to know if there is an out-of-the-box way to do it rather than writing the function for each and every field.

Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modal doesn't know you have input elements inside it, and that you want to validate it. Which is why nothing happens.

You can solve this in a few ways. The way i would recommend is to first create a form around your input fields with `<b-form>`.
Then when clicking on the `OK` button, we need to submit the form, as that will  then validate the inputs and show an error if the requirements are filled.

We will then use the `modal-footer` slot, to overwrite the default footer and replace it with our own buttons. For the cancel button we'll use the `cancel` method from the slot scope, so that it will function as default.

However, for the `OK` button, we will use the [form](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form.asp) attribute and `type="submit"`, to create a submit button for the form inside the modal.  The `form` attribute takes the `id` from our form.

If the form is submitted succesfully, we'll need to hide the modal manually. In the snippet we use `this.$bvModal.hide` for this.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      value: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onSubmit() {
      const {
        value
      } = this;
      alert(`Submitted: ${value}`);

      this.$bvModal.hide('my-modal')
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>


<div id="app" class="p-4">
  <b-btn v-b-modal.my-modal>Show Modal</b-btn>
  <b-modal id="my-modal" title="Form Modal" visible>
    <b-form id="my-form" @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
      <b-input v-model="value" required minlength="3" autofocus placeholder="Write something.."></b-input>
    </b-form>

    <template #modal-footer="{ cancel }">
      <b-btn @click="cancel">Cancel</b-btn>
      <b-btn variant="primary" type="submit" form="my-form">OK</b-btn>
    </template>
  </b-modal>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This worked for me.